# Red error lines on SQL temp tables

Tags: sql, ssms

When I create temp tables in SQL Server Management Studio and then I use them to view some records the temp tables have an error red line. However, they work just fine when I execute a query. Does anyone know how to remove these red lines?

Comment: There should be some sort of View or Display properties section in the Preferences menu somewhere. What have you tried already?

Comment: What error is shown? Can you describe the problem or show us a screenshot (blacken personal information)?

Answer (score 20):

You need to rebuild your IntelliSense cache.

The SSMS keyboard shortcut for this is <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Alternatively, you can go to Edit → IntelliSense → Refresh Local Cache.